# Default item showing in non-editable comboBox

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, textbox

I have a non/editable comboBox in my GUI C++ application (Visual Studio 2012) and want to select a default item/value in that box from my collection (all the items/value). Hope that someone can help me to make this possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't quite understood which control exactly you mean. In my understanding a textbox would be a editcontrol. but then you said you want to select one value out of many values, which would apply to a combobox control. Which is it?

Comment: I meant a comboBox, my mistake,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have filled your disabled combobox like this:

```
LPCTSTR s[] = {_T("Blue"), _T("Red"), _T("Yellow")};

CComboBox* pCombo = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO_COLOR);

if(pCombo)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        pCombo->AddString(s[i]);
    }
    pCombo->SetCurSel(1); // <- sets the default value. here it would be "Red"
}
```

As illustrated in the code snippet, you would simply do it by setting the currently selected item (index based)